# EXTRACT DATA FROM STRING IN SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to extract the data in string? For example below is the string format:

```
" in: xyz: abhi , product: NR (Ritti) ''
```

I want the output as `Ritti` from the above string.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't shout. Instead, show us what you tried and how it doesn't achieve your goal.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.Please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com//tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com//help). You might also want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried extracting by using susbstr and INSTR. Example, substr(field1, INSTR, field1,'(',1,1)+1, INSTR, field1,')'),1,1)-1). This is not giving me any output

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I am using oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one bracket closed value in the string then this can be useful.
for Oracle -

```
with string_value(str) as(
select 'in: xyz: abhi , product: NR (Ritti)' from dual
)
select substr(str,instr(str,'(')+1,instr(str,')',1)-instr(str,'(',1)-1) from string_value;
```

Comment: Good to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
select regexp_replace('in: xyz: abhi , product: NR (Ritti)','.*\((.*)\).*','\1') from dual;
```